# How to make sure that mlr take only 6 core

Tags: mlr

I am using following code on 8 core Linux and it takes all 8 cores (each of the 6 worker is taking 130% utilization)

```
    library(mlr); library(parallel); library(parallelMap)

# Load data
    iris_num <- iris; iris_num$Species <- as.numeric(iris_num$Species)

#create tasks
    traintask <- makeRegrTask(data = iris_num, target = 'Species')

#create learner
    lrn = makeLearner('regr.xgboost'); nthread <- min(6, detectCores());
    lrn$par.vals = list(print.every.n = 500, objective = "reg:linear", eval_metric="rmse", nthread = nthread)

#set parameter space

    params <- makeParamSet(
      makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower = 5L,upper = 20L), # 6
      makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L,upper = 20L), # 1
      makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
      makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1),
      makeIntegerParam("nrounds",lower=3000,upper=5000),
      makeNumericParam("lambda",lower=0.75,upper=1),
      makeNumericParam("lambda_bias",lower=0,upper=0.75),
      makeNumericParam("gamma",lower=0,upper=1),
      makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.01, upper = 0.05) # 0.3
    )

#set resampling strategy
    rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",iters=9L)

#search strategy
    ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)

#set parallel backend
    if(Sys.info()['sysname'] == "Linux") {
      parallelStartMulticore(cpus = nthread, show.info = T)
    } else parallelStartSocket(cpus = nthread, show.info = T)

    tune <- tuneParams(learner = lrn, task = traintask,resampling = rdesc,measures = rmse, par.set = params, control = ctrl, show.info = T)
```

**How to make sure that mlr take only 6 core**

Comment: Can you post which function of mlr you want to paralleize and which learners you are using?

Comment: And which learner?

Comment: @Shiv can you make a small reproducible example that includes the code you are using? As Lars notes, mlr will only use as many cores as you give it. This is most likely caused by the learner also accessing multiple cores, which can be changed in the learner params

Comment: Full working code is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nthread <- min(6, detectCores())
```

This line here is going to immediately execute and will always return 6 on an 8 core machine. You use this line on both the xgboost model and for the tuning. Each of your 6 tuning threads will attempt to create an xgboost model which wants 6 threads. So you are making 36 threads on an 8 core machine.

I'm unaware of a way to have mlr (or anything) respect the number of 'unused' cores. If you know you have a 6 core machine I would recommend manually breaking this up. For instance, give tuneParams 2 threads and give each xgboost model 2 threads. Since the tuneparams process will be idle and waiting to hear back from the xgboost models you could probably give the xgboost models 3 threads.

Answer (score 1):

mlr has no control over what the learners do internally -- if they are parallelised, you will end up using more cores. To be on the safe side, give it only e.g. 4 cores.